# Retrieve text of anchor within <li> element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm completely STUCK with this very simple task, I would be glad for any advice.

I've created a dropdown menu for user selection using `<ul>` and `<li>`. Once the user clicks on a certain menu Item (from the class `submen`), this item gets the class `active` assigned to it.

```
<ul id="firstid">
    <li id="secondid"><a href="#">Title1</a>
        <ul class = "submen">
            <li class = "active"><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to retrieve the text "Option1" since the user has selected this item in the above example and its class is `active`. How do I go about this using jQuery? This doesn't seem to work:

```
var selected_option = $("#secondid" ".submen" ".active" "a").text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chained selector looks like this:

```
var selected_option = $("#secondid .submen .active a").text();
```